# tar: Short all-caps file names not being archived/extracted

Tags: bash, debian, embedded-linux, tar, file-exists

**Edit**

After seeing 4ae1e1's suggestion, I decided to completely rework my post.

I am having a very strange problem with tar not archiving/extracting files with short, all uppercase names.  I am using an embedded PC running Debian Sarge and a YAFFS2 file system.

I have been trying to create a zipped tar archive that contains a file that has a all uppercase name that's three letters long (`AAA` for example).  After creating a text file named `AAA` in my working directory, I use the command that follows to create the archive:

```
tar cvzf "/home/Update.tgz" ./*
./AAA
```

As you can see, tar shows the file being added to the archive just fine and tar returns `0` indicating success.  When I try to extract the archive to the folder `/temp` with the following:

```
tar zxf "/home/Update.tgz" -C "/temp"
```

the file `AAA` is not extracted.  tar again returns `0` indicating the extraction was successful.  Running `ls` shows that the file `AAA` doesn't exist in `/temp`.

What is really strange is that if I rename the original file `AAA` to `Aaa` and recreate the archive, the file can be extracted successfully.

After finding this error I have tried many different filenames and every name that is all uppercase and three characters long or less shows this issue.  Has anyone ever seen a similar issue?  I would really appreciate any light anyone could shed on this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error by adding `touch $SRC_PATH/test1 $SRC_PATH/Aaa $SRC_PATH/AAA` right after `FILE_NAME=( "test1" "Aaa" "AAA" ) ` and deleting lines with RESULT and CALCSUM. I couldn't reproduce. Can you simplify your script to a minimal case for reproducing the error?

Comment: I know you don't want to upgrade from 2.05, but can you reproduce the problem in a newer version of `bash`?

Comment: Possibly, but not on my intended target without a considerable amount of busy work setting the embedded platform up to use `apt-get` or installing the new version manually.  I will try running the script on my workstation when I get back to my office and see if I can reproduce the error there.

Comment: Your new test case is so much easier to work with, thanks for that! Can you also add a `ls "$FILE"` or `ls /temp` that shows that the file is there, and then run with `bash -x yourscript` and paste the full output?

Comment: Ok, now I am really confused.  At first running my simplified code resulted in an error but now I can get it work just fine.  Running the test script at boot before the user logs in results in `+ FILE=/temp/AAA
+ ls /temp/AAA
/temp/AAA
+ [[ -f /temp/AAA ]]
+ echo '>> /temp/AAA found'
>> /temp/AAA found`

Comment: One suggestion about writing the question: you might want to put your distilled problem (as I understood it), i.e., case sensitivity problem of `tar`, at the top of the post. This way people don't need to read all the way down and eventually find out that all but the last 25% is irrelevant and distracting.

Comment: And one question that might lead to the right direction of thought: what's your filesystem?